# Read the Android Inbox From Desktop Application

Tags: java, android

I want to make a desktop application that can read the SMS from the android phone connected to the PC via USB cable. Is it possible I have searched the web to get any getting started point, there are tutorials about reading the SMS through android app... Can somebody guide me in the right direction, its not a request for code just want directions which way i should go ...

Comment: How about using Sockets? Read the message in android app, connect with desktop application using Socket and send sms content to it.

Comment: @JProgrammer if the android apps can use sockets then that could be a possible solution, can you provide some example of sorts... tnx

Comment: Yes android support Sockets (I think thats how it is able to make HTTP request :P). You can google it to find socket tutorial on android.

Comment: ok i will, tnx for the guidance `:) `

Comment: post it as an answer i sure will upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this link: http://ajack.org/blog/grabbing-sms-from-android
You can use Android Debug Bridge ( http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html) to read SMS from Your phone. Hope it helps.